# Access violation in official Microsoft WMI example

Tags: c++, wmi, variant

I'm trying to learn how the WMI works, but the default examples given have so far been atrocious.

Here's the example for calling the `Create` method of the `Win32_Process` class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--calling-a-provider-method

I have added proper error handling to this, we store the HRESULT of each call in a variable `hres` and check if the calls failed. As such:

```
        hres = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance);
        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            wprintf("Failed to get class. Error code = 0x%lx\n", hres);
            return hres;
        }
```

The code executes correctly right up until here:

```
    // Create the values for the in parameters
    VARIANT varCommand;
    varCommand.vt = VT_BSTR;
    varCommand.bstrVal = _bstr_t(L"notepad.exe");

    // Store the value for the in parameters
    hres = pClassInstance->Put(L"CommandLine", 0,
        &varCommand, 0);
    wprintf(L"The command is: %s\n", V_BSTR(&varCommand));
```

Where the `pClassInstance->Put` throws 'ol c5.

At this point, `hres` is `S_OK` for the call to `SpawnInstance` but these are the pointers we have for the class instances:

```
+pClass 0x000001c04e73fca0 IWbemClassObject *
-   pClassInstance  0x000001c04e749d60 IWbemClassObject *
-       IUnknown    {...}   IUnknown
-       __vfptr 0x00007ff9f8d0ee98 {fastprox.dll!const CWbemInstance::`vftable'{for `_IWmiObject'}} {0x00007ff9f8c6f450 {fastprox.dll!CWbemObject::QueryInterface(void)}, ...}  void * *
        [0x00000000]    0x00007ff9f8c6f450 {fastprox.dll!CWbemObject::QueryInterface(void)} void *
        [0x00000001]    0x00007ff9f8c907d0 {fastprox.dll!CWbemObject::AddRef(void)} void *
        [0x00000002]    0x00007ff9f8c8ffd0 {fastprox.dll!CWbemObject::Release(void)}    void *
+pInParamsDefinition 0x000001c04e743ca0 IWbemClassObject *
```

And `varCommand`:

```
+varCommand BSTR = 0x000001c04e74ffe8 tagVARIANT
```

The call stack:

```
    oleaut32.dll!SysAllocString()
    vfbasics.dll!AVrfpSysAllocString()
    wbemcomn.dll!CVar::SetVariant()
    fastprox.dll!CWbemInstance::Put()
>   Ele.exe!WMIConnection::InvokeMethod()
```

So it appears that bstrVal isn't being properly set, I think? I tried initializing it first with `VariantInit`, and I also tried dynamically allocating it on the heap instead. Neither resolved the issue:

```
        VARIANT varCommand;
        VariantInit(&varCommand);
        varCommand.vt = VT_BSTR;
        varCommand.bstrVal = _bstr_t(L"notepad.exe");
```

I also tried manually zeroing out the Variant buffer, to no effect. This is what we have for `bstrVal` in the memory dump when the access violation occurs:

```
bstrVal 0x000001c04e74ffe8 <Error reading characters of string.>    wchar_t *
               <Unable to read memory>                  wchar_t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

> ```
> varCommand.bstrVal = _bstr_t(L"notepad.exe");
> ```

The code creates a *temporary* `_bstr_t` object that goes out of scope, destroying the allocated `BSTR` memory, immediately after `varCommand.bstrVal` has been assigned to. Thus, `varCommand.bstrVal` is left dangling, pointing at invalid memory, when `varCommand` is passed to `pClassInstance->Put()`.  That is *undefined behavior*.

Use this instead to keep the `BSTR` alive until you are actually done using it:

```
_bstr_t str(L"notepad.exe"); 

VARIANT varCommand;
varCommand.vt = VT_BSTR;
varCommand.bstrVal = str;

// use varCommand as needed...

// DO NOT call VarClear() or SysFreeString()!
// You don't own the BSTR memory...
//VarClear(&varCommand);
```

Alternatively:

```
VARIANT varCommand;
varCommand.vt = VT_BSTR;
varCommand.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"notepad.exe");

// use varCommand as needed...

// You DO own the BSTR memory, so free it!
VarClear(&varCommand);
```

Otherwise, consider using [`_variant_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-class?view=msvc-170) instead, let it manage the memory for you:

```
_variant_t varCommand(L"notepad.exe");

hres = pClassInstance->Put(L"CommandLine", 0, &varCommand, 0);
wprintf(L"The command is: %s\n", V_BSTR(&varCommand));
```

Comment: I'll give you the checkmark since this was new information for me and very helpful, though the Microsoft example is deeply problematic aside from this temporarily variable issue, see my response if you're curious

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There are several forum posts on the internet asking about this example, with no solutions given, so I am very happy to provide this now.

The Microsoft example is using the incorrect classes.

In the Microsoft example, they attempt to call the `Put` method on a class instance of `Win32_Process` to set the parameters.

This is incorrect. We need to set the parameters via first getting the class method definition for `Win32_Process::Create` and then setting its parameters inside a *new instance* of `Win32_Process::Create`.

We additionally need to construct an instance of the `Win32_ProcessStartup` class object as it's a required input parameter for `Win32_Process::Create`.

In the example below I will populate one field of the `Win32_ProcessStartup` class instance, you can figure out the rest.

So this code from the Microsoft example:

```
 IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);

    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
    hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, 
        &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);

    IWbemClassObject* pClassInstance = NULL;
    hres = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance);

    // Create the values for the in parameters
    VARIANT varCommand;
    varCommand.vt = VT_BSTR;
    varCommand.bstrVal = _bstr_t(L"notepad.exe");

    // Store the value for the in parameters
    hres = pClassInstance->Put(L"CommandLine", 0,
        &varCommand, 0);
    wprintf(L"The command is: %s\n", V_BSTR(&varCommand));
```

Becomes (sans error handling for readability):

```
        // Get the class object
        hres = pClass->GetMethod(lpwMethodName, 0,
            &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);

        hres = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance);

        // Get the Win32_ProcessStartup class object
        IWbemClassObject* pStartupObject = NULL;

        hres = pSvc->GetObject(_bstr_t(L"Win32_ProcessStartup"), 0, NULL, &pStartupObject, NULL);

        // Create an instance of the Win32_ProcessStartup class object
        IWbemClassObject* pStartupInstance = NULL;

        hres = pStartupObject->SpawnInstance(0, &pStartupInstance);

        // Create the value for the ShowWindow variable of the Win32_ProcessStartup class
        VARIANT varParams;
        VariantInit(&varParams);
        varParams.vt = VT_I2;
        varParams.intVal = SW_SHOW;
        
        // And populate it
        hres = pStartupInstance->Put(_bstr_t(L"ShowWindow"), 0, &varParams, 0);

        // Get the method definition for Win32_Process::Create and store it in pInParamsDefinition
        hres = pClass->GetMethod(_bstr_t(lpwMethodName), 0, &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);

        // Spawn an instance of the Create method and store it in pParamsInstance
        IWbemClassObject* pParamsInstance = NULL;

        hres = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pParamsInstance);

        // Now we can set the parameters without error
        hres = pParamsInstance->Put(_bstr_t(L"CurrentDirectory"), 0, pvCurrentDirectory, 0);
```

Please note that all of these `hres` returns should be checked for failure.

The definition for `Win32_ProcessStartup` is provided here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processstartup

And the definition for the `Create` method of `Win32_Process`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/create-method-in-class-win32-process